# I have non-const ID3D11ShaderResourceView*, and the DirectX function requires const one

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, directx-11

I have some problem: I have **non-const** `ID3D11ShaderResourceView*`, and the DirectX function requires **const** one.

My code:

```
class Texture{
    ID3D11ShaderResourceView * textureRes;
    ...
};

class Model{
    void render(...){
    ...
    ID3D11ShaderResourceView * texture 
        = baseMaterial->getDiffuseTexture()->textureRes;
context->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, texture);
    }
    ...
};
```

And for it, I get error:

```
error C2664: 'ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetShaderResources' 
    : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'ID3D11ShaderResourceView *' 
    to 'ID3D11ShaderResourceView *const *'
```

**My question is:** 
how I can pass my `baseMaterial->getDiffuseTexture()->textureRes` of non-const type to `context->PSSetShaderResources`?

Some kind of casting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires 'ID3D11ShaderResourceView *const *', **two asterisks** means pointer to pointer.
You can pass either:

- address of your `ID3D11ShaderResourceView*`

  `context->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &texture);`
- or an array of `ID3D11ShaderResourceView*` if you need to bind multiple SRVs in one call

  `auto arrayOfTextures = { srv1,  srv2, srv3 };
  context->PSSetShaderResources(0, numberOfTextures, arrayOfTextures);`

See documentation of [ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetShaderResources method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476473%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is not the const it's the fact that it wants a pointer to a pointer. (See there are two *s). Probably you need to pass &texture as the parameter

This is because the parameters is actually a pointer to an array of pointers (you can pass more than one). So if you only want to pass one you need to pass the addres to pretend it's a single element array

Comment: Indeed! Thank you. Stackoverflow community fast as always :)
Added reference and it works now:
context->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &texture)
I like both your answers, but I will mark Drop'ed one because of more complex (helpfull for others) - anyway, voted up both of you :)

Comment: @PolGraphic let's call symbol `&` *an ampersand*. It has nothing common with C++ references here.